# Rails nested form associations loading in order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm not sure of the correct terminology for this but I'll try and explain it;
I have a fixtures(model) form with associations for a team model and a competition model, currently this works fine as all competitions and teams are loaded to choose from, However I would prefer to first choose the competition then only the teams within that competition would be available instead of having to choose from every team.

I'm using the simple_form gem, below is the fixtures form partial;

```
    - simple_form_for @fixture do |f|
  %p
    = f.association :competition
  %p
    = f.association :home
  %p
    = f.association :away
  %p
    = f.date_select :date
  %p
    = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll need to use something besides simple_form for the competition pick list. You need to add a `:onchange` call to that select input to then grab the relevant teams from to populate the other pick lists. Something like this:

```
<p>
  <%= select_tag "source_type_event", 
    options_for_select(Lead::VALID_SOURCE_EVENT_TYPES.collect {|p| [ p, p ] }, "" ),
    :onchange => "var pars = 'event_type=' + this.value; var aj = new Ajax.Updater('lead-events', '/get_lead_events',
    {method:'get',asynchronous:true, parameters: pars});" %>
</p>
<p id="lead-events">
</p>
```

I use this to pull a list of lead events based on a source type and populate the p#lead-events with a new select list based on the selected source type.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your answer... where does "Lead::VALID_SOURCE_EVENT_TYPES" come from?

Comment: Sorry, I was copying some existing code. It's constant array in the model Lead. Something like ["Order","Phone Call","Email"]. The key is the :onchange call that calls something to populate the p#lead-events with a new picklist.